# Suppose that the events A, B, and C are independent. Show that $A^c$ and (B∪C) are independent.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I think that if I can show that $A^c$, $B^c$, and $C^c$ are independent, then i can use the fact that $P(B∪C)=1-P(B^c ∩ C^c)$ to prove it. However, I don't know how to get to that point, or really if that's the right direction. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Well, using that $P(A^{\complement})=1-P(A)$ is a way  to get to that point..

Comment: I made a proof but it relies on using the fact that $P(A ∩ B^c ∩ C^c)=P(A)P(B^c)P(C^c)$, and I don't know how to show that this is true.

Comment: "and I don't know how to show that this is true" Use $$P(A\cap B^c\cap C^c)=P(A)-P(A\cap B)-P(A\cap C)+P(A\cap B\cap C)=\ldots$$